# Groovy add string to result

Tags: groovy

I have a following groovy code, which returns name of folders in some directory:

```
def folder = "C:\\WinPackages-Development";
def (dir1, value2) = OPERATOR1.tokenize( ' | ' )
def finaldir = "${folder}\\${dir1}\\${APP_TYPE1}\\"
def baseDir = new File(finaldir);
def results = baseDir.listFiles()*.name
return results
```

Can anyone hint me, how to add some additional (actually fake) string into "result"?
E.g. right now it returns "dir1, dir2". How to return "dir1, dir2, somecustomdir" ?

Comment: `results.add('something')` just before return or `return results + [ 'something', 'other' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` works as well in one line:

```
def results = baseDir.listFiles()*.name + 'someFakeString'
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers in the comments work, you can also use the left shift operator:

```
def method() {
  def result = [1,2,3]  

  result << 4
}

println("method returns: ${method()}")
```

which results in:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy
method returns: [1, 2, 3, 4]

~>
```

when run.

Answer (score 0):

Just add custom object (e.g. String) to the end of your List by << operator. You can also use java-style add method.

```
def someMethod(def yourCustomObject){
List result = []
result << yourCustomObject// equals to result.add(yourCustomObject)
return result
}
```